# Better wait until new year, or I ask now about the interview result

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, recruitment, follow-up

So on the 10th December, I was interviewed (not by a user, but HR a interviewer). It's already 16 days after the interview, but I have not received any update about the result.

I think because of Christmas and the New Year holiday, a lot of people from 
the recruitment division have taken holiday, so I didn't get any update about the result. But I'm really curious now, should I ask / follow up about the interview result now, or wait until new year (maybe 2nd Jan / 3rd Jan to follow up)?

EDIT:
It is the banking corporate industry, and I applied for the IT Trainee Program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may vary from industry to industry, example: in software, 16 days is just too long.

You are right, the attendance is thin around the holiday season, but that's all more reason to have this wrapped up early (before the holiday begins).

Anyways, if you're not done it already, send an e-mail to follow up about the next steps. Since the holidays are around, use that to formulate the email - take the opportunity to share season's greetings, and add a polite follow-up question.

If you've got the phone numbers you could have tried calling them, but now since the holidays have already started, chances are less that you'll find the people you need to be working. You have to wait it out till the holidays are over and people are back at their desks.

Comment: Okay , i better wait next weeks .. and i will update about the industry that i apply

Comment: can I ask about this to the one person from the recruitment division? via Whatsapp, because I was very close to her, and she offered me this job. But when I took the offline test, she was on leave because she was going to give birth, so she could not take care of this process and might be given to someone else, before she took the paid leaves, the process seemed fine and fast, maybe only take 1 week per process, but i scared that it will be distrubing her

Comment: @Jacqueline Normally I would have said yes, but if you mention she's on maternity leave, I'd not be inclined to bother them - more so because it's the holiday season and being on leave, it's very less likely that she;ll be knowing the current whereabouts of the process. If I were you, i'll just leave her best wishes for the new year, and hope she gets back when she has time, instead of directly engaging with her about the process.

Comment: okay then , she will get back in 3 months XD , she will return in march , and it will too long to wait , so maybe i will follow up about it myself to the recrutiment division ..

Comment: @Jacqueline That would be the correct thing to do, in my opinion. Happy holidays and best of luck.

Comment: I disagree that 16 days is too long for software at this time of year (at least in the aus/nz locales), but the rest of your advice here is great.

Comment: @PlayerOne Thanks, but jusy FYI I was mentioning about the timeline in general, not during the holiday season.

Comment: @SouravGhosh fair enough, I think the season is important for this question though, since it's included in both the title, and the middle (and largest) paragraph of the question (I upvoted, because your advice about what to do is on point, I just want to point out that there's no need to stress about not hearing anything yet at this specific time of year) .

Comment: @PlayerOne Again you are correct, and I'm also saying, that because the holiday season was about to begin, I'd have expected the interviewers to move things faster,  and arrive at a conclusion sooner than later, to avoid carry-over load to a new year. :) However, now that holidays are already here, we can only wait till it's over.

Comment: a hard decision for me tho XD, because after my internship period over , i hope i can get this job or if i can say is change my internship status into a fulltime employee , so i dont need to find a work again .. and continue to work in this company haha , but i will try to wait until new year holiday is over , then i will follow up

Comment: Agreeing with @PlayerOne - While this is likely industry/company dependent - in software and finance, for example, most companies have hiring freezes this time of year, so it's not at all uncommon to hear nothing until January after a last minute (relatively speaking) phone screen with an HR person.